# synchronized a variable through a method from a static class

Tags: java

I've been reading about synchronization in java and I've got a question.
So the examples I've seen are either a class creates a synchronized block on a local object. Or a synchronized method. Neither of those two is ideal for my situation. So I have a static instance of a class that holds all the data from the entire application. Variables on that class are created as "private", I created getters to retrieve those values. Some of those values need to be accessed by only one thread at a time from difference classes across the application. Since they are created as private I'm using the synchronized block as follows...

```
public class Music{
    private ArrayList<Album> albums;
    private static Music musicObject = new Music();

    public ArrayList<Album> getAlbums()
    {
         return albums;
    }
    public Music getInstance()
    {
         return musicObject;
    }
}

public class Album {

    private Date releaseDate;

    private String singer;

    public Date getReleaseDate()
    {
        return releaseDate;
    }

    public String getSinger()
   {
        return releaseDate;
   }  
}
public class AlbumRetrieval
{
   private Music data;

   public AlbumRetrieval()
   {
      data = Music.getInstance();
      synchronized(data.getAlbums())
      {
          //No other thread can access the albums variable in here
      }
   }
}
```

Can I lock/synchronized an external variable by accessing it through a method call.?

Comment: what is `data.getAlbums()` returns? Please share some more information.

Comment: Why do you need to lock something that outside?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do that. If you couldn't, the code would not compile.

`synchronized()` takes an object as "argument". It makes sure that two threads can't enter a synchronized block on this object at the same time.

So, if `data.getAlbums()` returns a list, the posted code synchronizes on this list, and no other thread will be able to enter a block that is synchronized on this exact same list while the first thread has not exited its synchronized block.

Note that it's quite a bad strategy to enforce thread-safety. You'll have, every time you access data, to make sure to synchronize correctly. This is very error-prone, and can easily lead to deadlocks. You'd better encapsulate all the accesses to the albums into a well-defined class, which takes care of proper synchronization, rather than return a non-thread-safe list and rely on each and every caller to apply the appropriate synchronization.